# SNIHostName configuration in Camel

Tags: apache-camel, sni

Trying to configure SNIHostName in our camel application? Can someone help us how to configure using spring DSL

appreciate your help

Tried to

```
<camel:sslContextParameters id="mySslContext">
    <camel:clientParameters>
        <camel:secureSocketProtocols>
            <camel:secureSocketProtocol>TLSv1.2</camel:secureSocketProtocol>
        </camel:secureSocketProtocols>
        <camel:sniHostNames>
            <camel:sniHostName>{{kong.gw.server.host}}</camel:sniHostName>
        </camel:sniHostNames>
    </camel:clientParameters>
</camel:sslContextParameters>
```

but getting error